# HTTP 500 error on WSE1.0 POST to WSE2.0 web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wse2.0

I have a web service that uses Web Service Extensions 2.0 to receive an XML post from a WSE1.0 web service. I have no control over the WSE1.0 service, nor are they able to tell me what the error actually is.

I have managed to set up some diagnostics based on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885203.aspx

The underlying error is:

```
System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Calling XmlSerializer [Read Request]
    Method: Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer#6503226::Deserialize(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol+SoapEnvelopeReader#18307385=.., (null))
    Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol#58529038::ReadParameters()
    ProcessId=1656
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=1
    DateTime=2009-09-29T15:13:13.6703985Z
    Timestamp=1754775019015
System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Return from XmlSerializer [Read Request]
    Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol#58529038::ReadParameters()
    ProcessId=1656
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=1
    DateTime=2009-09-29T15:13:13.6703985Z
    Timestamp=1754775027350
System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Calling SoapExtension
    Method: Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesExtension#540121::ProcessMessage(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessageStage#8=AfterDeserialize)
    Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage#4861097::RunExtensions(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension[]#43749873=[1], System.Boolean#1=True)
    ProcessId=1656
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=1
    DateTime=2009-09-29T15:13:13.7016473Z
    Timestamp=1754775128848
System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Return from SoapExtension
    Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage#4861097::RunExtensions(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension[]#43749873=[1], System.Boolean#1=True)
    ProcessId=1656
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=1
    DateTime=2009-09-29T15:13:13.7016473Z
    Timestamp=1754775136909
System.Web.Services.Asmx Error: 0 : Exception caught in System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler#54078809::CoreProcessRequest.
    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: SOAP header path was not understood.
    ProcessId=1656
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=1
    DateTime=2009-09-29T15:13:13.7016473Z
    Timestamp=1754775137949
System.Web.Services.Asmx Error: 0 : Exception Details:
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: SOAP header path was not understood.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderHandling.SetHeaderMembers(SoapHeaderCollection headers, Object target, SoapHeaderMapping[] mappings, SoapHeaderDirection direction, Boolean client)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
    ProcessId=1656
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=1
    DateTime=2009-09-29T15:13:13.7016473Z
    Timestamp=1754775143263
```

Comment: I have rewritten the web service to use WSE1.0. It appears that WSE1.0 and WSE2.0 are not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSE1.0 and WSE2.0 are not compatible. You can use any of the WSE versions regardless of .NET framework, just by using the appropriate library.